# Perfomance issue on solr 4.8 server

Tags: solr4

Performance issue on solr 4.8 server.

CPU % utilization has been very high when we receives more search requests from the site, the solr server is not properly responding.

Index size of the solr core is 45GB.

Please find the solr server details (solr info url response details) as below:
solr-spec-version       "4.8.0"
solr-impl-version       "4.8.0 1589874 - thetaphi - 2014-04-24 20:54:59"
lucene-spec-version     "4.8.0"
lucene-impl-version     "4.8.0 1589874 - thetaphi - 2014-04-24 20:38:58"
jre version         "1.7.0_79"
processors          16
memory
    free            "1.6 GB"
    total           "3.9 GB"
    max         "3.9 GB"
    used            "2.3 GB (%58.6)"

systemLoadAverage       30.32
committedVirtualMemorySize  65003704320 (60GB+)
freePhysicalMemorySize      31435997184
freeSwapSpaceSize       8579280896
processCpuTime          1160371710000000
totalPhysicalMemorySize     63459581952
totalSwapSpaceSize      8589930496
openFileDescriptorCount     161
maxFileDescriptorCount      60000

Please give help to tuning the solr 4.8 server.

Comment: Your numbers indicate a very well-balanced machine and Solr setup, so you need to provide more details on usage: How many concurrent queries do you issue, do you index at the same time, can you provide a sample query, what are your expectations for response times and throughput?

Comment: How many concurrent queries do you issue, do you index at the same time?

Concurrent requests per server per sec : 26  (when requests increases to 26 server load increases)

Yes we do have replication at every 6 min



what are your expectations for response times and throughput?

Response time should be less than 200ms

Throughput required minimum more than 60 request per sec as per server configuration.

Comment: can you provide a sample query?

/solr/music/select?fl=id&version=1.2&wt=json&json.nl=map&q=id:(2095965 2095967 2095964 2095966) AND  ( rights:"1242_2_AA" OR rights:"1242_6_AA" OR rights:"1242_2_XW" OR rights:"1242_6_XW" OR rights:"1242_2_XS" OR rights:"1242_6_XS" OR rights:"1242_2_XC" OR rights:"1242_6_XC" OR rights:"1242_2_XF" OR rights:"1242_6_XF" OR rights:"1242_2_IN" OR rights:"1242_6_IN" OR rights:"1242_2_XA" OR rights:"1242_6_XA" ) &start=0&rows=4